# DIsable HardwareButton on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have some basic app on windows phone 8.1, and in that i have regular buttons, for navigate or exit application. I want to disable HardwareButton for back/exit, so if anyone press it, application will not exit.
Any help?

Btw, i tried:

```
Public void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = false;     

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewrite the HardwareButtons_BackPressed method on `App.xaml.cs` file.

Also if you have handled the Event, you have to set `e.Handled = true` to tell the system you have already handled the event and dont push the event below in the queue.

For more and examples see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639128.aspx).

Comment: No luck... I searched about rewrite App.xaml.cs but i can't find anything. 
And about this MSDN page, it's says if i want to navigate with backbuton, and i want to disable it.

Comment: The glue is to set the `e.Handled = true` so the system isn't looking to get the event handled by any other method lower in the execution tree. If you let the user navigate back (like the example in MSDN) or do nothing is your decision.